# Unlucky number 13

Tags: python

I came across this problem [Unlucky number 13!](http://qa.geeksforgeeks.org/4344/the-unlucky-13)  recently but could not think of efficient solution this.

#### Problem statement :

N is taken as input.

> N can be very large 0<= N <= 1000000009

Find total number of such strings that are made of exactly N characters which don't include "13". The strings may contain any integer from 0-9, repeated any number of times.

```
# Example:

# N = 2 :
# output : 99 (0-99 without 13 number)

# N =1 :
# output : 10 (0-9 without 13 number)
```

My solution:

```
N = int(raw_input())

if N < 2:
    print 10

else:
    without_13 = 10

    for i in range(10, int('9' * N)+1):
        string = str(i)
        if string.count("13") >= 1:
            continue
        without_13 += 1
    print without_13
```

### Output

The output file should contain answer to each query in a new line modulo 1000000009.

Any other efficient way to solve this ? My solution gives time limit exceeded on coding site.

Comment: Please include problem specification in question. External links may expire.

Comment: I tried this but it gives time limit exceeded error on coding site I am trying this problem. There might be some efficient way

Comment: In the problem statment you missed the ending of the sentence "Find total number of such strings that are made of exactly N characters __which don't include 13__".

Comment: Thanks updated the problem statement.

Comment: FYI: This is [OEIS A004189](https://oeis.org/A004189).

Comment: And FYI, even with the recurrence relation in the OEIS A004189 and caching you will not get your answer accepted...this is a question cautiously made for divide and conquer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this can be solved via recursion:

```
ans(n) = { ans([n/2])^2 - ans([n/2]-1)^2 }, if n is even
ans(n) = { ans([n/2]+1)*ans([n/2]) - ans([n/2])*ans([n/2]-1) }, if n is odd
```

Base Cases:

- `ans(0)` = 1
- `ans(1)` = 10

It's implementation is running quite fast even for larger inputs like `10^9` ( which is expected as its complexity is `O(log[n])` instead of `O(n)` like the other answers ):

```
cache = {}

mod = 1000000009

def ans(n):
    if cache.has_key(n):
        return cache[n]

    if n == 0:
        cache[n] = 1
        return cache[n]
    if n == 1:
        cache[n] = 10
        return cache[n]

    temp1 = ans(n/2)
    temp2 = ans(n/2-1)

    if (n & 1) == 0:
        cache[n] = (temp1*temp1 - temp2*temp2) % mod
    else:
        temp3 = ans(n/2 + 1)
        cache[n] = (temp1 * (temp3 - temp2)) % mod

    return cache[n]

print ans(1000000000)
```

[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/TNqxJw)

**Explanation:**

Let a string `s` have even number of digits 'n'.
Let `ans(n)` be the answer for the input `n`, i.e. the number of strings without the substring `13` in them.
Therefore, the answer for string `s` having length `n` can be written as the multiplication of the answer for the first half of the string (`ans([n/2])`) and the answer for the second half of the string (`ans([n/2])`), minus the number of cases where the string `13` appears in the middle of the number `n`, i.e. when the last digit of the first half is `1` and the first digit of the second half is `3`.

This can expressed mathematically as:

```
ans(n) = ans([n/2])^2 - ans([n/2]-1)*2
```

Similarly for the cases where the input number `n` is odd, we can derive the following equation:

```
ans(n) = ans([n/2]+1)*ans([n/2]) - ans([n/2])*ans([n/2]-1)
```

Comment: Realy great! This is the fastest solution. However it needs some additional memory for cache than iterating like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/39879256/2842758 but as we store only cutted by modulo values they are not realy heavy and memory consumption is not a problem.

Comment: Mathematical expression for the even case uses multiplication at the end rather than power of 2 operator, was not able to edit it since it was less than 6 characters.

Comment: This code throw the error `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison` for larger numbers. In fact, it fails for 1000000000 itself in python3

Answer (score 7):

I get the feeling that this question is designed with the expectation that you would initially instinctively do it the way you have. However, I believe there's a slightly different approach that would be faster.

You can produce all the numbers that contain the number 13 yourself, without having to loop through all the numbers in between. For example:

2 digits:
13

3 digits position 1:
113
213
313 etc.

3 digits position 2: 131
132
133 etc.

Therefore, you don't have to check all the number from 0 to n*9. You simply count all the numbers with 13 in them until the length is larger than N.

This may not be the fastest solution (in fact I'd be surprised if this couldn't be solved efficiently by using some mathematics trickery) but I believe it will be more efficient than the approach you have currently taken.

Comment: "You simply count all the numbers with 13 in them until the length is larger than N" How do you do this ?

Comment: Instead of thinking of them as numbers, think of them as strings that coincidentally contain numeric characters. There are a limited number of positions that the string "13" can exist in the string and a limit combination of numeric characters that can surround it. This is how the numbers must be structured: <0...n Numeric><"13"><0...n Numeric>. Therefore you can produce all the strings containing 13 yourself.

Answer (score 4):

This a P&C problem. I'm going to assume 0 is valid string and so is 00, 000 and so on, each being treated distinct from the other.

The total number of strings not containing 13, of length N, is unsurprisingly given by:

```
(Total Number of strings of length N) - (Total number of strings of length N that have 13 in them)
```

Now, the Total number of strings of length N is easy, you have 10 digits and N slots to put them in: `10^N`.

The number of strings of length N with 13 in them is a little trickier.
You'd think you can do something like this:

```
=> (N-1)C1 * 10^(N-2)
=> (N-1) * 10^(N-2)
```

But you'd be wrong, or more accurately, you'd be over counting certain strings. For example, you'd be over counting the set of string that have two or more 13s in them.

What you really need to do is apply the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to count the number of strings with 13 in them, so that they're all included once.

If you look at this problem as a set counting problem, you have quite a few sets:

```
S(0,N): Set of all strings of Length N.
S(1,N): Set of all strings of Length N, with at least one '13' in it.
S(2,N): Set of all strings of Length N, with at least two '13's in it.
...
S(N/2,N): Set of all strings of Length N, with at least floor(N/2) '13's in it.
```

You want the set of all strings with 13 in them, but counted at most once. You can use the inclusion-exclusion principle for computing that set.

Comment: What does P&C stand for?

Comment: @BioGeek Permutation and Combination

Answer (score 4):

Let `f(n)` be the number of sequences of length n that have no "13" in them, and `g(n)` be the number of sequences of length n that have "13" in them.

Then `f(n) = 10^n - g(n)` (in mathematical notation), because it's the number of possible sequences (`10^n`) minus the ones that contain "13".

Base cases:

```
f(0) = 1
g(0) = 0
f(1) = 10
g(1) = 0
```

When looking for the sequences *with* "13", a sequence can have a "13" at the beginning. That will account for `10^(n-2)` possible sequences with "13" in them. It could also have a "13" in the second position, again accounting for `10^(n-2)` possible sequences. But if it has a "13" in the *third* position, and we'd assume there would also be `10^(n-2)` possible sequences, we could those twice that already had a "13" in the first position. So we have to substract them. Instead, we count `10^(n-4)` times `f(2)` (because those are exactly the combinations in the first two positions that don't have "13" in them).

E.g. for g(5):

```
g(5) = 10^(n-2) + 10^(n-2) + f(2)*10^(n-4) + f(3)*10^(n-5)
```

We can rewrite that to look the same everywhere:

```
g(5) = f(0)*10^(n-2) + f(1)*10^(n-3) + f(2)*10^(n-4) + f(3)*10^(n-5)
```

Or simply the sum of `f(i)*10^(n-(i+2))` with `i` ranging from `0` to `n-2`.

In Python:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=1024)
def f(n):
    return 10**n - g(n)

@lru_cache(maxsize=1024)
def g(n):
    return sum(f(i)*10**(n-(i+2)) for i in range(n-1))  # range is exclusive
```

The `lru_cache` is optional, but often a good idea when working with recursion.

---

```
>>> [f(n) for n in range(10)]
[1, 10, 99, 980, 9701, 96030, 950599, 9409960, 93149001, 922080050]
```

The results are instant and <s>it works for very large numbers</s>.

Comment: For any `n` we need all values from `1` to `n-1`. So for n>1024 current code begins to work very slowly. Actually the maxsize of cache is almost the maximum possible `n` value. As  soup boy says, we need to be able to work with n=10^9. So there should be some other idea, because so many cached values would not fit in memory.

Comment: I agree with Leonid.

Comment: @soupboy The solution of Anmol Singh Jaggi works for pretty high numbers (10^6), but also not for your upper bounds (in a reasonable amount of time). Look at the OEIS page for better formulas. There is a non-recursive formula (`((5+sqrt(24))^n-(5-sqrt(24))^n)/(2*sqrt(24))`), but it doesn't work at high numbers either because of floating point number limits.

Comment: @L3viathan Ok Got it.

Comment: My solution would work even for large values if I used caching. I will soon update my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

In fact this question is more about math than about python.
For N figures there is 10^N possible unique strings. To get the answer to the problem we need to subtract the number of string containing "13". 
If string starts from "13" we have 10^(N-2) possible unique strings. If we have 13 at the second possition (e.i. a string like x13...), we again have 10^(N-2) possibilities. But we can't continue this logic further as this will lead us to double calculation of string which have 13 at different possitions. For example for N=4 there will be a string "1313" which we will calculate twice. To avoid this we should calculate only those strings which we haven't calculated before. So for "13" on possition `p` (counting from 0) we should find the number of unique string which don't have "13" on the left side from `p`, that is for each p 
number_of_strings_for_13_at_p = total_number_of_strings_without_13(N=p-1) * 10^(N-p-2)
So we recursevily define the total_number_of_strings_without_13 function.

Here is the idea in the code:

```
def number_of_strings_without_13(N):
    sum_numbers_with_13 = 0
    for p in range(N-1):
        if p < 2:
            sum_numbers_with_13 += 10**(N-2)
        else:
            sum_numbers_with_13 += number_of_strings_without_13(p) * 10**(N-p-2)

    return 10**N - sum_numbers_with_13
```

I should say that `10**N` means 10 in the power of N. All the other is described above. The functions also has a surprisingly pleasent ability to give correct answers for N=1 and N=2.

To test this works correct I've rewritten your code into function and refactored a little bit:

```
def number_of_strings_without_13_bruteforce(N):
    without_13 = 0
    for i in range(10**N):
        if str(i).count("13"):
            continue
        without_13 += 1
    return without_13

for N in range(1, 7):
    print(number_of_strings_without_13(N),
          number_of_strings_without_13_bruteforce(N))
```

They gave the same answers. With bigger N bruteforce is very slow. But for very large N recursive function also gets mush slower. There is a well known solution for that: as we use the value of `number_of_strings_without_13` with parameters smaller than N multiple times, we should remember the answers and not recalculate them each time. It's quite simple to do like this:

```
def number_of_strings_without_13(N, answers=dict()):
    if N in answers:
        return answers[N]

    sum_numbers_with_13 = 0
    for p in range(N-1):
        if p < 2:
            sum_numbers_with_13 += 10**(N-2)
        else:
            sum_numbers_with_13 += number_of_strings_without_13(p) * 10**(N-p-2)

    result = 10**N - sum_numbers_with_13
    answers[N] = result
    return result
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination !! This should work but since input range is too large. I am getting memory and time limit exceeded errors. Just thinking if this can be solved using greedy or dynamic programming technique.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to L3viathan's comment now it is clear. The logic is beautiful.

Let's assume `a(n)` is a number of strings of `n` digits without "13" in it. If we know all the good strings for `n-1`, we can add one more digit to the left of each string and calculate `a(n)`. As we can combine previous digits with any of 10 new, we will get `10*a(n-1)` different strings. But we must subtract the number of strings, which now starts with "13" which we wrongly summed like OK at the previous step. There is `a(n-2)` of such wrongly added strings. So `a(n) = 10*a(n-1) - a(n-2)`. That is it. Such simple.

What is even more interesting is that this sequence can be calculated without iterations with a formula https://oeis.org/A004189 But practically that doesn't helps much, as the formula requires floating point calculations which will lead to rounding and would not work for big n (will give answer with some mistake).

Nevertheless the original sequence is quite easy to calculate and it doesn't need to store all the previous values, just the last two. So here is the code

```
def number_of_strings(n):
    result = 0
    result1 = 99
    result2 = 10
    if n == 1:
        return result2
    if n == 2:
        return result1
    for i in range(3, n+1):
        result = 10*result1 - result2
        result2 = result1
        result1 = result
    return result
```

This one is several orders faster than my previous suggestion. And memory consumption is now just O(n)

P.S. If you run this with Python2, you'd better change `range` to `xrange`

Answer (score 2):

This python3 solution meets time and memory requirement of HackerEarth

```
from functools import lru_cache

mod = 1000000009

@lru_cache(1024)
def ans(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if n == 1:
        return 10

    temp1 = ans(n//2)
    temp2 = ans(n//2-1)

    if (n & 1) == 0:
        return (temp1*temp1 - temp2*temp2) % mod
    else:
        temp3 = ans(n//2 + 1)
        return (temp1 * (temp3 - temp2)) % mod

for t in range(int(input())):
    n = int(input())
    print(ans(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem on
https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/the-unlucky-13-d7aea1ff/

I haven't been able to get the judge to accept my solution(s) in Python but (2) in ANSI C worked just fine.

Straightforward recursive counting of a(n) = 10*a(n-1) - a(n-2) is pretty slow when getting to large numbers but there are several options (one which is not mentioned here yet):

1.) using generating functions:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g%28n%2B1%29%3D10g%28n%29+-g%28n-1%29%2C+g%280%29%3D1%2C+g%281%29%3D10
the powers should be counted using squaring and modulo needs to be inserted cleverly into that and the numbers must be rounded but Python solution was slow for the judge anyway (it took 7s on my laptop and judge needs this to be counted under 1.5s)

2.) using matrices:
the idea is that we can get vector [a(n), a(n-1)] by multiplying vector [a(n-1), a(n-2)] by specific matrix constructed from equation a(n) = 10*a(n-1) - a(n-2)

```
| a(n)   | = | 10 -1 | * | a(n-1) |
| a(n-1) |   | 1  0  |   | a(n-2) |
```

and by induction:

```
| a(n)   | = | 10 -1 |^(n-1) * | a(1) |
| a(n-1) |   | 1  0  |         | a(0) |
```

the matrix multiplication in 2D should be done via squaring using modulo. It should be hardcoded rather counted via for cycles as it is much faster.

Again this was slow for Python (8s on my laptop) but fast for ANSI C (0.3s)

3.) the solution proposed by Anmol Singh Jaggi above which is the fastest in Python (3s) but the memory consumption for cache is big enough to break memory limits of the judge. Removing cache or limiting it makes the computation very slow.

Answer (score -1):

You are given a string S of length N. The string S consists of digits from 1-9, Consider the string indexing to be 1-based.

You need to divide the string into blocks such that the i block contains the elements from the index((i 1) • X +1) to min(N, (i + X)) (both inclusive). A number is valid if it is formed by choosing exactly one digit from each block and placing the digits in the order of their block

number

Comment: Plz send the answer for this