# The Unlucky 13 Challenge in HackerEarth

Tags: swift, algorithm, runtime-error, permutation, equation

I recently  came across this coding challenge - [The Unlucky number 13](https://stackoverflow.com). (The last problem in the section)

**Problem Statement:**

Write a program to calculate the total number of strings that are made of exactly **N** characters.
None of the strings can have "**13**" as a substring.
The strings may contain any integer from 0-9, repeated any number of times.

**Input:**
N is taken as input where ****0<= N <= 1000000009****.

**Output:**
The output should be the answer modulo 1000000009.

***My Solution:***

I tried to solve it using a simple equation I came up with.

> ans = 10^n - ((10^(n-2)) * (n-1))
>
> Subtracting the possibilities with 13 as substring from the total number of possibilities.

I wrote the code in Swift. It works when N is small. But I get a runtime error on submission (probably when N is large).

Here is my code:

```
let input = Int(readLine()!)
if let n = input as? Int{
    var ans = getPowerOfTen(n)
    ans = ans - getPowerOfTen(n-2) * (n - 1)
    print(ans % 1000000009)
}

// Did not import any library to calculate the power   

 func getPowerOfTen(_ num: Int)->Int{
        var ans = 1
        var n = num
        while(n > 0){
            ans = ans * 10
            n = n - 1
        }
        return ans
 }
```

I was hoping to get help for two questions.

1. Could you help me find the run time issue?

   [This is the screenshot of the runtime error I get from the site.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wwDG.png)
2. Could there be a better way to solve this?

> I found this in Array & Strings problem section. I did not use any
> array though. I think this equation works.

Comment: Two problems. First, `getPowerOfTen` is going to be really slow when `n` is a billion. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring for a faster method. Second, you need to apply the modulo inside the `getPowerOfTen` function. Otherwise, the calculation results in a billion-digit number. That's probably where the runtime error is coming from.

Comment: N is very large, you cant use an iterative while loop to calculate the power, you need [big mod](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-compute-mod-of-a-big-number/). Also you are not using modular arithmetic correctly, you can get some help from [here](https://www.hackersfriend.com/articles/modular-arithmetic-for-competitive-programming)

Comment: The formula is incorrect. The number with, say, _two_ occurrences of 13 is _twice_ accounted for.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868990/unlucky-number-13) answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula seems correct. There are two problems with your solution.

```
1: Time complexity
2: Overflow Issue
```

---

### Time complexity

You are using *naïve technique* when calculating `10^n mod m`. You are using a simple loop from `1` to `n` which results in a complexity of `O(n)`. There is a very popular technique known as [Binary Exponentiation](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/binary-exp.html) of calculating `a^b mod m` in `O(logn)`. This technique is used widely in competitive programming to solve various questions.

---

### Overflow Issue

Inside the while loop, you are repeatedly updating `ans` like this:

```
ans = ans * 10
```

*When the value becomes big enough, `ans` will become negative* since it will unable to store that value. This is known as [Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). One good way to spot that there is a chance that overflow may happen, is when in the question it is mentioned:

```
The output should be the answer modulo 1000000009
```

This is a sign that the program setter themselves know that the calculation will be big so they ask to output the answer in this format.

---

I have not provided  *the algorithm for Binary Exponentiation as it already there in the provided link*. The algorithm used there also takes care of overflow issue.
I have also provided *another link for Integer Overflow* in case you want to check it out.

If you still face any trouble, do comment.